# Evernote business account create note

Tags: c#, evernote

I made an application to create a bunch of notebooks at the same time and group them into a stack. This worked perfectly until the client upgraded to a business account. Now, permission errors occur when the app tries to create a notebook. 
Basic idea of the code:

```
session = ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession;
session.SupportsLinkedAppNotebook = true;
ENNoteStoreClient store = session.PrimaryNoteStore;
Notebook notebook = new Notebook();
notebook.Name = name;
notebook.Stack = stackname;
notebook.DefaultNotebook = false;
store.CreateNotebook(notebook);
```

This results in a EDAMUserException with errorcode PERMISSION_DENIED.
Is there any special flow I need to follow in order to create notebooks in a business environment?

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate and then use `session.BusinessNoteStore`.